# Is there any method for me to automate the printer driver installation?

Tags: windows, powershell, zebra-printers

I want to install printer driver on Windows machine using powershell script, rather then clicking next options repeatedly. I have tried /S argument for silent mode but it's going in to the silent mode and prompts on the screen for next and finish, then to select the printer model (Zebra gx30t) and install it. I want to automate the complete process.

Comment: As you have no code this isn't a coding related issue and so it is off-topic for [so]. You may be able to get help on [su] - where a general question about computing hardware and software is on-topic. Voting to move this question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly powershell, but I have previously been able to automate print driver installation with the following command

```
printui /ia /m "<driver_name>" /f "\\path\to_drivers\oemsetup.inf" /h x64
```

This should install the driver silently, note that it requires the .INF file for the driver

Explanation of parameters (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rundll32-printui)

```
/ia Installs a printer driver by using an .inf file.
/m[model]   Specifies the driver model name. (This value can be specified in the .inf file.)
/f[file]    Species the Universal Naming Convention (UNC) path and name of the .inf file name or the output file name, depending on the task that you are performing. Use /F[file] to specify a dependent .inf file.

/h[architecture]    Specifies the driver architecture. Use one of the following: x86, x64, or Itanium.
```

Comment: Thank you halv. If I'm not wrong we need to extract the printer .exe file in order to obtain the .INF file. Unfortunately, I'm unable to find the inf file after the extract. Can I also add the same line to a .batch file? Thanks for your help again, really appreciated.

Comment: Correct, you would have to find the .inf file somehow, I usually find it within the same package as the driver installation.. but I believe it is also possible to extract the .inf file from an installed driver, so that might be an option. And yes, this works as a batch file too